# How to join SVG parts into bigger parts?

Tags: svg

Well I needed a vector map of The Regions of France, So I did some research and I found this one here :
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/76/D%C3%A9partements_et_r%C3%A9gions_de_France_vide.svg?uselang=fr

but this one is divided into department, one level more than I need, so I'm trying to join the parts into regions.

Any Idea how to do that easily ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the file in a Text editor (e.g. Notepad++) and search and replace #808080 with #f4e2ba. This will make all the thin lines the same color like the background and therefore invisible.

Comment: Thank you, Well actually I downloaded InkScape and I opened it with it, and found layers like : Regions, Departments, ... . Thank you anyway